# How to make HTTP POST call with application/zip and multipart/form-data using plugin io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin in Groovy

Tags: gradle-plugin

I am using the below code to make HTTP POST call to the server with the content type as `application/zip` and `multipart/form-data` using `io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin`.(One of the example shared [here](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/#_request))

```
plugins {
    id "io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin" version "0.1.1"  
}
import groovyx.net.http.ApacheEncoders
import groovyx.net.http.*
import groovyx.net.http.HttpConfigs.BasicHttpConfig
import groovyx.net.http.OkHttpBuilder.OkHttpToServer
import static groovyx.net.http.MultipartContent.multipart

File msFile =new File("C:\\GradlePOC\\POC_1\\btest.zip");
OkHttpBuilder.configure {
    request.uri = 'https://example.com'
    request.auth.basic 'ABC', 'XXXXX'
    request.encoder('application/zip'){ BasicHttpConfig config, OkHttpToServer req->
        req.toServer(new FileInputStream(
            msFile
        ))
    }
}.post {
    request.uri.path = '/application/applications/3547/binaries'    
    request.contentType = 'multipart/form-data'
    request.body = multipart {      
        field 'name', 'data'
        part 'filename', 'btest.zip', 'application/zip', msFile     
    }
    request.encoder 'multipart/form-data', OkHttpBuilder.&multipart    
}
```

But the above code is not working for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these changes:

```groovy
plugins {
    id "io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin" version "0.1.1"  
}

import groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.MultipartContent
import groovyx.net.http.OkHttpEncoders
import groovyx.net.http.ChainedHttpConfig
import groovyx.net.http.ToServer

File msFile =new File("C:\\GradlePOC\\POC_1\\btest.zip");

OkHttpBuilder.configure {
    request.uri = 'https://example.com'
    request.auth.basic 'ABC', 'XXXXX'
    request.encoder('application/zip'){ ChainedHttpConfig config, ToServer req->
        req.toServer(new FileInputStream(msFile))
    }
}.post {
    request.uri.path = '/application/applications/3547/binaries'    
    request.contentType = 'multipart/form-data'
    request.body = MultipartContent.multipart {      
        field 'name', 'data'
        part 'filename', 'btest.zip', 'application/zip', msFile     
    }
    request.encoder 'multipart/form-data', OkHttpEncoders.&multipart    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only working way for me:

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25'),
  @Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-okhttp:1.0.4')
])

import groovyx.net.http.*


String BASE_URL = '[HOST_SERVER]'
String URI_PATH = '[UPLOAD_ENDPOINT]'

File msFile = new File('C:\\GradlePOC\\POC_1\\btest.zip')

// Post a file (okhttp)
OkHttpBuilder.configure {
    request.uri = BASE_URL
    request.auth.basic 'admin', 'admin'
}.post {
  request.uri.path = URI_DOC_UPLOAD
  request.contentType = 'multipart/form-data'
  request.body = MultipartContent.multipart {
    field 'name', 'data'
    part 'filename', msFile.name, 'application/octet-stream', msFile
  }
  request.encoder 'multipart/form-data', OkHttpEncoders.&multipart
}
```

It worked for me to upload PDF files.